# Can I power a nodeMCU using 3.7 battery

Tags: power-supply, voltage, lithium-ion, nodemcu

I have a nodeMCU board (3.3V) and a li-ion battery with 3.7 V. Is it alright to give the power supply from that battery?

Comment: What do the voltage requirements say? A Lithium Ion battery is as high as 4.2V when full and as low as 3.3V when empty.

Comment: the board needs 3.3V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot safely power a nodeMCU directly from a lithium ion cell.

The nominal voltage of a lithium ion cell is 3.7V.

[image]
<sub>[Image source.](https://siliconlightworks.com/li-ion-voltage)</sub>

As you can see, the voltage from a lithium ion cell is usually at 3.7V or higher.  It only drops below 3.7V when it is near "empty."

The nodeMCU has a maximum input voltage of 3.6V:

[image]
<sub>[Image source.](https://espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0a-esp8266ex_datasheet_en.pdf)</sub>

It is intended to operate from a regulated 3.3V source.  The nominal 3.7V of the lithium cell is above the maximum rated voltage.

Notice, though, that the nodeMCU will work with a supply voltage as low as 2.5V.  All you need is a regulator that will output 3.3V or lower.

I've use LM3671 3.3V regulator modules with nodeMCU modules for this very reason.  They can regulate anything above about 3.5V to 3.3V.  When the input voltage drops below 3.5V, the output "tracks" the input - the output voltage is just the input voltage minus a couple of hundred millivolts.

Connect the LM3671 input to the lithium ion cell, then connect the LM3671  output to the 3.3V pins of the nodeMCU.  Make sure to never power the nodeMCU from the 3.3V pins and the USB connector or Vin at the same time.

---

The electrical specifications above are for an ESP8266.  They are very similar to the ESP32 specifications.

---

Make sure your lithium cell has an under voltage shutoff.  If you discharge a lithium ion cell too far, it will be damaged.  A damaged lithium ion cell can explode or catch fire.